# Natural Language Understanding for a Spoken Dialog System

Tags: nlp, speech

I am looking to implement a task based spoken dialog system as a part of my project. I am finding it difficult to build a Natural Language Understanding (NLU) unit for the system. It is the part where the words(utterances) by the user are "understood" by the system to map the speech to a particular action. It is a complicated process but if anyone has any practical experience in building spoken dialog systems, any ideas about how to start going about this will be much appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that your application effectively requires NLU rather than maybe just voice recognition?

Comment: Yes. I am done with the Automatic Speech Recognition (ASR).

Comment: @Themach this is too large a topic for one question. Have you checked the available literature on the subject?

Comment: @Themach Out of curiosity, what did you use for ASR ?

Comment: Android's in built speech recognizer from google.

Comment: The two simple dialog models are finite-state based models, and frame-based models. Then, there are myriads of more sophisticated models. What kind of dialog are you trying to support ? A few examples would be useful to give you more precise directions.

Answer (score 3):

It is quite a broad topic, but since I am fresh of an investigation in this field, let me share what I learned.

Usually, the first step is to parse the grammatical structure of the sentence (particurlarly, the dependencies among its words). This will give you an output like this:
http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml#Sample

I am interfacing to the Stanford Parser using this python wrapper:
https://github.com/dasmith/stanford-corenlp-python

The second step, usually, is to map each word to a "sense", doing what is called Word-Sense Disambiguation (WSD).

Once you know the sense of each word and the relationship between them you should be able to understand the sentence and to trigger the desired action.

There is no open and free system able to do all of that out of the box for generic sentences. This is particularly hard for spoken language.

For example, grammar parsers like the Stanford Parser usually provide language models trained on the type of text of newspaper articles, this tends to be quite different from spoken language. Very likely you will want to train a new language model adding to the training "treebank" the type of sentences you expect to receive in your system. (the Stanford Parser provides such model trainer application).

Unfortunately, there are no good general purpose software libraries to make Word-Sense Disambiguation (WSD). The main reason is that there is not yet a practical reference for word "senses". The de-facto standard in this field is still WordNet, but apparently even humans often disagree in the mapping between a word and a "synset". In other words, WordNet meanings are too fine grained to provide a reliable mapping.

Very often, you will want to build up your own database of meanings (usually structured in trees), creating it as much coarse grained as practical for your application.
There are many approaches to map words to such coarse grained meanings, one of the simplest, but still quite effective, is the good old naive Bayes Classifier.
Another approach that I have not yet experimented myself is to use the information about "word frames" (ie a certain meaning of a certain word will have certain relationships with the words around it).

Anyway, the reality is that it is a though and open problem. Initially, you should focus on solving it for a specific sub-domain.